# azure key vault The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors

Tags: .net, azure-keyvault

I have an azure key vault that i can access through a self signed certificate and an application. This app succesfully retrieves keys and values from the key vault on several computers. On certain computers however, it errors and returns the following error: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors

I have explicitly granted the user and network service read rights with the certificate manager so i'm not sure what else i am missing for those computers.

Does anyone have a clue what i could be missing?
thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my nxfilter was blocking access to the key vault do check that if you have one